# Excel: referencing a portion of file name only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help, i'm looking to reference a portion of my file name in an excel cell, see below example:

File name: 000_XYZ_ABC_DEF ; I need to reference the ABC portion (but this won't be limited to only 3 letters as this varies) - is there a formula I could use that would cater for the variance as well as only referencing this portion?

thank you

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://exceljet.net/formula/get-workbook-name-only

Answer (score 0):

Well, very brutal with MID() and FIND() but works:

[image: my working example]

Basic explanation is that MID() takes the characters from a string from the start points and end point you define.

The use of find() is to locate the second underscore which is the start point (plus 1 though) and the position of the 3rd underscore which with the position of the second gives the number of characters to return.

It will be good practice to take it all apart.

Edit: I have added the complete function, so that you can copy it directly:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1)+1)-FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1)-1)
```

In your comment you have not included in your function the "_" which is the precise bits of the text FIND() is looking for. Compare mine to yours from your comment:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("",A1,FIND("",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND("",A1,FIND("",A1,FIND("",A1,1)+1)+1)-FIND("",A1,1)+1)-1
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks so much for taking the time to respond. It's possible my question wasn't clear enough, however, when I retyped your formula into the cell I want the portion of the file name referenced in, I got a #VALUE error. See below what I typed in:  =MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1,1)+1)+1)-FIND("_",A1,1)+1)-1  

Seems as though this formula is referencing the top left cell on the worksheet, however  I need it to reference the portion of the saved file's name, I'll give another example if I can post an image (still pretty new)

Comment: If you look, my find function is looking for the underscore not blanks which you have typed... ie _  ...

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, again, thanks so much for taking the time to respond! When inserting the function you included for me, the cell returns output of #VALUE! going to see if I can post a screen shot of what's happening

Comment: seems as though I can't post an image here, looks like this might not work out :( unless you know of a way I can post an image somewhere for you to see?

Answer (score 0):

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",30)),60),30))
```

[image]