# Getting the average number of times a number appears between other numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my cells I have three possible different values, 1 ,0 or ND. I want to get the average number of times 0 appears between the 1s. 
But I cannot seem to get it, I have been playing around with `=AVERAGE(COUNTIF(A60:C60,  0))`. It seems simple but I cannot figure it out.
So I want the average number of times that 0 appears between 1s in the whole row.

imagine each cell is a day. 1s represent fail and 0 represent pass. If the cell has failed that day it is fixed that night. what i want to find out is when i fix a failed cell what is the average amount of days pass before that cell fails again

[image]

Comment: no sorry mike you answered the wrong question

Comment: Or are you asking the wrong question. Or asking it badly.

Comment: @SolarMike its okay that you answered the wrong question, easy mistake to make if you didnt read the question correctly. i have added in some further text which may help you understand.

Comment: Well, I might consider find(), but will let you make the effort.

Comment: No worries if you don't know how to do it. its a tricky one.

Comment: I now know how I would approach it and would target the last complete period between fails.

Comment: I think we are thinking along the same lines. count the runs of zeros between the 1s and divide that by the total number of zeros to get the average. tricky to put into code.

Comment: Well, consider what I did here and see what you can make of it`; https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075833/4961700

Answer (score 2):

#### A formula only solution to show the idea of how to calculate it

This solution doen't need VBA but a helper row.

Imagine the following data in row 1.

[image]

Row 2 is a helper row to calculate the average:

- A2 is empty.
- B2 write the formula `=IF(B1=1,COUNTIF($A$1:B1,0)-SUM($A$2:A2),"")` and copy it to the right.

The average is then calculated with `=AVERAGE(2:2)`

The numbers in row 2 are the count of `0` that are in front of the `1` in row 1. All `ND` get just ignored.

---

#### But this is the same result as

```
=COUNTIF(1:1,0)/COUNTIF(1:1,1)   '<-- = average
```

Because the `=AVERAGE` is actually the sum of zeros devided by the amount of ones. So this formula is all you need, even no helper column is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of "0"s per line with `=COUNTIF(A60:C60,0)` and in a new cell the number of "1"s per line using `=COUNTIF(A60:C60,1)`.

As second step, divide the value obtained with the 1st formula through the value obtained with the 2nd formula. This should give you the average number of 0s in relation to the 1s. Hope that helps.

Comment: That is looking at the proportion of 0 vs 1s. thank you however i am not looking for that.  imagine each cell is a day. 1s represent fail and 0 represent pass. If the cell has failed that day it is fixed that night. what i want to find out is when i fix a failed cell what is the average amount of days pass before that cell fails again.

Comment: @pete800 the proportion between 0s and 1s is the exact same result as the avarage amount of 0s between the 1s. Mathematically that is the same. See my answer for an illustration of that. Amount of 0s devided by amout of 1s is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, my reputation is too low to make comments. 
I agree with the solution of M.S. with small corrections.

1. Making the life a bit easier I would ignore the starting 0, so I deleted them. Anyway they are not between ones.
2. The number of 1s shall be reduced with 1, while there are one less intervals between the ones.

After it the ration shall give the average:

```
=COUNTIF(A60:C60,0)/(COUNTIF(A60:C60,1)-1)
```

Comment: Actually what is the reason to delete the first 0? It represents a day that passed without fail. The OP is looking for *"average amount of days pass before that cell fails"*. So he is looking for the *average amount of 0s before 1s*. If you remove the first 0 you mess up the data and the result is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry that it was not clear. The second sentence of the question is: "I want to get the average number of times 0 appears between the 1s." The  0 at the beginning is literally not between 1s. I wrote it  in my first point. I do understand what you are criticizing. You can be rights. You can assume that the first 0 represents a whole period (means the number before is 1).  You also can assume that it was just started any day. It would ruin the statistic. I was not assuming, but removing the not good defined part.